# Ошибка: невозможно задать event "ZedGraphControl.MouseMove", так как отсутствует доступная функция доступа add

Tags: c#

```
 <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wfHost" Margin="10,125,22,40" Padding="2,0,0,0">
            <a:ZedGraphControl x:Name="zedGraph" MouseMove="zedGraph_MouseClick"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
 public void zedGraph_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            // Сюда будут записаны координаты в системе координат графика
            double x, y;

            // Пересчитываем пиксели в координаты на графике
            // У ZedGraph есть несколько перегруженных методов ReverseTransform.
            zedGraph.GraphPane.ReverseTransform(e.Location, out x, out y);

            // Выводим результат
            string text = string.Format("X: {0};    Y: {1}", x, y);
            label2.Content = text;

        }
```

Ошибка: 1>C:\Users\Виктор\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\GeoWpf\GeoWpf\MainWindow.xaml(20,50): error MC3080: невозможно задать event "ZedGraphControl.MouseMove", так как отсутствует доступная функция доступа add.

Comment: А как определено `ZedGraphControl.MouseMove`?

Comment: Ага, нашёл — а если поменять `object sender` на `ZedGraphControl sender`?